# bringSubviewToFront for CALayer

Tags: iphone, calayer

I'm wondering if there is a way to bring layer on top of others layers of view. Something like `bringSubviewToFront` does for `UIView` class. I think it can be done with `zPosition` property of the `CALayer` but this means I have to check `zPosition` for all layers and then set proper value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the code (given that `layer` is your `CALayer`)

```
[layer retain];
CALayer *superlayer = layer.superlayer;
[layer removeFromSuperlayer];
[superlayer addLayer:layer];
[layer release];
```

will do what you want, albeit in a roundabout way.

Comment: how to swap the z-index of two layers?

Answer (score 4):

It's even easier. If `sublayerToBeMovedToFront` is the layer you're moving and `itsSuperLayer` is, well, its superlayer, just say:

```
[itsSuperLayer addSublayer:sublayerToBeMovedToFront];
```

The `addSublayer`call simultaneously unhooks`sublayerToBeMovedToFront` from wherever it was in the sibling list and rehooks it as the last (ie, frontmost-positioned, visually "on top") sublayer. This is exactly analogous behaviour to that of [`aUIView addSubview:]`

Answer (score 1):

This category will achieve what you are talking about…

> CALayer+Additions.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>
@interface CALayer (Additions)
- (void)moveToFront;
@end
```

> CALayer+Additions.m

```
#import "CALayer+Additions.h"
@implementation CALayer (Additions)
- (void)moveToFront {
    CALayer *superlayer = self.superlayer;
    [self removeFromSuperlayer];
    [superlayer addSublayer:self];
}
@end
```

`#import "CALayer+Additions.h"` within your project, and you will find a new method, `moveToFront` is now available to your `CALayer` instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `CALayer` for performance you should also try using only `UIImageView`'s. In my case it turned out to be a few FPS faster. (maybe from the `UIImage` to `CGImage` conversion that I needed to perform in every image attribution)